# How to show $c-b\lt b-a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, semigroups

**The question:**

> > Let $G$ be an Arf semigroup and $a\lt b\lt c$ be three consecutive elements in $G$. How to show that $c-b\lt b-a$ and how to show that this is not necessarily the case for every semigroup.

*Note*

**the definition of arf semigroup**

let $W=\{i_0 =0, i_1,...\}$ be a semigroups of nonnegative integers, where $i_1\lt i_2\lt ...$. Then $W$ is an Arf semigroup if the collection $i_h-i_h=0$, $i_{h+1}-i_h$, $i_{h+2}-i_h$,... Is a semigroup for all choices of $h\ge 0$

**What I understand from the question:**

$a\lt b\lt c$ be three consecutive elements in $G$. That's, the only element of $G$ in the open real interval $(a,c)$ is $b$

And in order to show $c-a\lt b-a$, I need to show the elements of $G$ get closer.

But, I cannot do these. Please help me solving this question. Thank you:)

Comment: Is it about *multiplicative* or additive semigroup?

Comment: Dear @Berci do you have an idea for my question?

Comment: Can you give an example of an Arf semigroup?

Comment: Arf semigroups are certain subsets of the non-negative integers closed under addition @Magdiragdag

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Let $\alpha \ge 1$ be an integer. $H=(3, 6\alpha +2, 6\alpha+4)$ is an Arf semigroup, I think. @Magdiragdag

Comment: So it's an *additive* semigroup, not multiplicative?

Comment: Hmm... Okay I understand. Well, can show the solution please? @Magdiragdag

Comment: Sorry I saw the answer right now. Thank you:) @Magdiragdag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false and it is irrelevant that $G$ has any structure at all (except that it's infinite).

$G = \{ i_0, i_1, \dots \} \subseteq {\mathbb N}$ with $i_0 < i_1 < i_2 < \dots$ and the questions asks to show that $i_1 - i_0 > i_2 - i_1 > i_3 - i_2 > \dots$. But this is impossible, as these are all natural numbers.

Comment: Well, if the question says that $c-b\ge b-a$, the claim is true. Right?

Comment: I don't know :-) At least it's not this trivially false. But please make sure you have the question exactly right (and check it for an example!).

Comment: Okay thank you:) but if you mind, can you expand the reason why this is false? I don't understand enough. I cannot say which part I don't understand, but this is something which is not enough:( thank you so much:)

Comment: Not trivially false means? Under which conditions, this question is true?

Comment: As (still) stated, the claim is the question is obviously false (-1) as I explained above - you get an infinite strictly decreasing sequence of natural numbers, which is impossible. Note that you yourself already say in the question "I must show that the elements of $G$ get closer", which is a big red flag.

Comment: Okay thanks for helping:)